# Declaring a connection string in console application

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am creating a console app and I have a connection string in the app.config file.  When I try to reference this in my code I get an error on the configuration manager (ie its underlined).

```
    Public Function getTPLvalue() As String
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GasNominationsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select tpl from JADhist where dateSubmitted = (select MAX(datesubmitted) from JADhist)", conn)
    Dim TPL As String = (cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    conn.Close()
    Return TPL
End Function
```

any ideas

Comment: I needed to import the system.configuration reference

Comment: Show us the app.config and add reference to system.configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reference the namespace `System.Configuration` using:

```
Imports System.Configuration;
```